# How would you use the Subgraph Isomorphism problem to solve Clique?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, clique

I currently have a program that solves subgraph isomorphism. It will return 1 if there is an isomorphic subgraph and 0 if there is not.

I'm trying to use this implementation to solve the clique problem (whether or not a graph G contains a clique on k vertices). I've been stuck on this for a while so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the following for the subgraph isomorphism:

> the subgraph isomorphism problem is a computational task in which two graphs G and H are given as input, and one must determine whether G contains a subgraph that is isomorphic to H.

Indeed you solved the problem. If a subgraph of `G` is isomorphic to `K_m` (a clique with `m` number of vertices), it contains a clique with the size of `m` (and if it is not true, it does not contain any clique with size `m`).

Comment: Since the clique problem only takes in 1 graph, G, what would be the second graph that my isomorphic subgraph program takes in? I think that's the part where I'm stumped.

Comment: The second graph is the reduced, isolated k-clique.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm still confused on how to get the k-cliques from the original graph. Is there some pseudocode I can look at for that?

Comment: The problem in your question isn't to find the cliques, just to answer "yes" or "no" about whether a clique exists.